# How to use IORef with lenses?

Tags: haskell, atomic, haskell-lens, ioref

Wondering how best to combine the [Control.Lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package with `IORef`s. Specifically I'd like to be able to use `atomicModifyIORef` with lenses so that i can supply a function of type `a -> (a, b)` and return a value from the operation. Code snippet:

```
let inc x = (x+1, x)
ior <- newIORef ((1, 1) :: (Int, Int))
thisShouldBe1 <- ior & atomicModifyIORef ?? _1 inc -- this is the bit I'm stuck on
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In principle, the lens operator needed is actually `%%~`, which is just a convenience synonym for `id`. However, due to an annoying incompatibility in the tuple orderings used in `atomicModifyIORef` and the `(,) a` `Functor`, it needs some swapping around to work. I don't think the resulting operator is predefined, but I've given it the preliminary name `swappedId` below.

Note that the `Lens` type is defined as

```
type Lens s t a b = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

It turns out that if you let `f` be the `(,) a` `Functor`, this almost perfectly fits the type you want to use to transform your `inc`, except that you'd really have wanted the `a` to be the last element of the tuple instead of the first.  After fixing this up, here is what I ended up with:

```
import Data.IORef
import Control.Lens

l `swappedId` f = f & mapping swapped %~ l

main = do
    let inc x = (x+1, x)
    ior <- newIORef ((1, 1) :: (Int, Int))
    thisShouldBe1 <- atomicModifyIORef ior $ _1 `swappedId` inc
    print thisShouldBe1
    print =<< readIORef ior
```

Answer (score 3):

I found it convenient to define a helper function for manipulating `IORef`s using `Lens`es. As mentioned by Ørjan Johansen, `atomicModifyIORef` uses a different pair order than the `Functor` instance of `(,)`, so we need to swap. And since you'd like have the function of type `a -> (a, b)`, we need to swap this function as well.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
import Control.Lens
import Data.IORef
import Data.Tuple (swap)

-- | Atomically modifies an 'IORef' using a lens
atomicModifyWithLens :: IORef a -> Lens a a b c -> (b -> (c, r)) -> IO r
atomicModifyWithLens ref l f =
    atomicModifyIORef ref (swap . traverseOf l (swap . f))

main = do
    let inc x = (x+1, x)
    ior <- newIORef ((1, 1) :: (Int, Int))
    thisShouldBe1 <- atomicModifyWithLens ior _1 inc
    print thisShouldBe1
```